# Java(Kotlin) Socket Server. Read continously

Tags: java, sockets, server, kotlin

My server reading looks like this:

```
private fun init() {
        val inStream = BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream())
        val bytes = ByteArray(bufferSize)

        outStream = DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream())


        while (true) {
            val count = inStream.read(bytes, 0, bufferSize)

            if (count >= 0) {
                server.onReceive(this, bytes, count)
            }

        }
    }
```

First read waits until bytes received. But second doesn't wait. And loop is running forever and count is -1. I want to read bytes only when they received.

Comment: declare `var count` before loop and only reassign the value inside it?

Comment: @Pawel Why? What difference would that make?

Answer (score 2):

> And loop is running forever

You're looping at end of stream. If `count` is -1 you should close the socket and exit the loop.

> and count is -1

Exactly my point.

Comment: Let's say my client sent message. Server opened connection, closed. Client send again. Server again opened and closed ? What is best way? Client will send many messages. Every time server should open and close connection?

Comment: That's a new question, and it doesn't bear on this answer in any way, but it's better for the server to loop reading and responding to requests until the client closes the connection. Then the client can *decide* whether to use one persistent connection or a new one per request. Persistent is better, but on the other hand the client should not tie up an idle connection for very long.